# Есть ли тут грамматическая ошибка?

Tags: грамматика

> Листья используются для здоровья, ветви — для веников, кора — для письма, поделок, дёгтя и разведения огня.

Можно ли посчитать ошибкой то, что листья используЮтся, а кора используЕтся? То есть можно ли ставить тире после слова "кора" для пропуска слова "используются"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ошибки нет.

Пропущенное сказуемое может быть не только в другом числе, но и в другом роде (в зависимости от своего подлежащего). Вот примеры:

> *Они **стояли** друг против друга: он – растерянный и смущённый, она – с выражением вызова на лице.*

Пропущенные сказуемые: ***стоял***, ***стояла***. [**Источник**](https://videotutor-rusyaz.ru/uchenikam/teoriya/225-nepolnyepredlogeniya.html).

> *Мне всё послушно, я же – ничему* (Пушкин). Вторая часть сложного бессоюзного предложения (***я же – ничему***) представляет собой неполное предложение, в котором пропущено сказуемое (ср.: *Я же **не послушен** ничему*).

[**Неполные предложения**](https://licey.net/free/4-russkii_yazyk/40-kurs_russkogo_yazyka_sintaksis_i_punktuaciya/stages/722-26_nepolnye_predlozheniya.html)